# Why does my Android device with ARMv8-based CPU cores (Exynos 7 Octa 7870) not support the arm64-v8a ABI or 64-bit instruction set?

Tags: android, arm, cpu-architecture, arm64, abi

I have an Android device (SAMSUNG Galaxy Tab Active2 SM-T397U) which has the **Exynos 7870 SoC**. The [Exynos 7870](http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/exynos/products/mobileprocessor/exynos-7-octa-7870/) uses eight **Cortex A-53** Cores [that implement the **Armv8-A architecture**.](https://developer.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-a/cortex-a53) However, it doesn't support the arm64-v8 ABI and it isn't clear which instruction set it supports.

There are multiple Android apps that can extract the System CPU and SoC information of the device.

---

Using one such app (AIDA64), it lists the Instruction Set as **"64-bit ARM"** but the Supported ABIs as only armeabi-v7a and armeabi (screenshot below).

[AIDA64 Screenshot listing SoC Model and supported Instruction Sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCGxi.jpg)

---

Another app (DroidInfo) lists the CPU architecture as **"ARMv7-A"** and the instruction sets as also "armeabi-v7a" and "armeabi" (Screenshot below)

[DroidInfo Screenshot listing SoC Model and supported Instruction Sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EF24.jpg)

---

I was under the impression that CPU Cores that implemented the v8a architecture were able to [utilize armeabi-v8a ABI for most optimized performance.](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html)

If that is the case I would like to understand why this SoC only supports the armeabi-v7a ABI and **NOT the arm64-v8a** ABI. The Android developer page on ABIs states for the arm64-v8a ABI:

> "This ABI is for ARMv8-based CPUs that support AArch64."

Are there ARMv8-based CPUs that support a different instruction set? The [ARM reference manual on the ARMv8 Instruction Set](https://www.element14.com/community/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/41836-102-1-229511/ARM.Reference_Manual.pdf) states that ARMv8 has two instruction sets - the **A64 used in AArch64 state** and **A32 in AArch32 state**. Is it possible that this CPU is **locked** in the Aarch32 state? If that is the case, what be the reason for doing so or is it even possible and is there a way to confirm that this is the case?

I am also not able to understand why the architecture/instruction set of the Exynos 7870 would being inconsistently reported by these apps, presumably they use the same APIs under the hood to grab this information or if there is a more robust way of getting the "true" information?

If I am completely on the wrong path, I would appreciate some pointers of where my understanding is wrong.

Comment: An abi is a compiler thing an instruction set is an instruction set nothing dictates they have to be associated with each other.  For a particular instruction set any number of ABIs can be created and that many or more compilers can conform to their favorite.  Is that the confusion here?

Comment: arm64-v8 ABI  is not an instruction set it is an ABI.  This is kind of like saying I am limited to the 26 letter latin alphabet so that means all language must be american english because there is no other way to use those letters except to spell american english words.  How could it be possible to use those letters any other way for any other reason.

Comment: armv8 cores have an armv7 compatibility mode and lower execution level code can be forced/limited to the armv7, aarch32, classic arm instructions.  You may be in a situation where the operating system is 64 bit but the applications are limited to 32.

Comment: an abi may dictate an instruction set but an instruction set is not limited to nor forced to an abi.  most/everyone may CHOOSE to use a common abi, but it is just a choice when implementing a compiler.

Comment: note that arms abis have changed over time and are to some extent incompatible and that was before the 64 bit thing happened yet all point at the same instruction set.

Comment: if you want to develop for an operating system and against a shared library you need to conform to that software using the right tools and settings.  instruction set isnt really part of the conversation, right tool, right version, right setting, you get the correct mix of instructions, its a side effect of conforming to the rules for that OS and the libraries being linked/shared.  the os doesnt necessarily even drive this very much as the system calls are a whole other spec.

Comment: It might be that Linux Kernel is running in 32-bit mode (for whatever reason, possibly memory reduction because of pointers), which would limit userspace to 32-bit.